# What is the equivalent of matlab's smooth3 function in c++?

Tags: c++, matlab

In Matlab there is [this example](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/smooth3.html) that smooth a matrix in 3D,

```
data = rand(10,10,10);
data = smooth3(data,'box',5);
...
```

I wanat to know what is its equivalent with c++,
any one know the code? thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add some background of what you are trying to achieve? C++ doesn't provide native support for such specialized high-level functionality, so you'll have to resort to 3rd party libraries. It appears you ultimately want to do 3D visualization, in which case VTK is an excellent choice.

Comment: Type `edit smooth3` at Matlab console to display the function's code. You could re-implement it then in C++, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks all, actually, for the visualization I have my own OpenGL program, what I want is the smoothing itself, but let's try the VTK or implement it from the Matlab code!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [VTK](http://www.vtk.org) for this.